# Best ways to debug an arch installation?

Tags: arch-linux

I am (to the best of my knowledge) following the [ArchLinux Installation Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide). I have successfully installed ArchLinux on another computer before, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong this time.

I make it through the entire guide no issues, I install grub and my `intel-ucode` microcode. However when it comes to the last step, to reboot, I have been failing. If the USB is plugged in, on reboot I am sent back to the USB boot menu. If I unplug the USB, the computer boots into the BIOS immediately.

It's hard to google search (especially lately) on how to troubleshoot this issue. Has anyone run into similar issues before? I am not failing to create the EFI partition or filesystem or anything like that either, the partition table looks exactly how it goes in the guide.

Here is the `fdisk -l` output for the boot drive:

```
/dev/sda1   2048    1050623     1048576   512M          EFI System
/dev/sda2   1050624 5244927     4194304   2G            Linux swap
/dev/sda3   5244928 937701375   932456448 444.6G        Linux root (x86-64)
```

I did install `efibootmgr` at the same time I installed grub, no issues were reported.

Comment: Sounds like grub may be your issue, try reinstalling. Did you install `efibootmgr `? Are you dual booting? Is your EFI partition on the same drive as the Arch installation? Is there another EFI partition on another drive in your machine. Add the output of `lsblk` to your question.

Comment: If you can boot the system in some kind of rescue mode from the installation, you should try and use the `efibootmgr` command to check if the UEFI firmware was actually told to boot something from the EFI partition. Or try and (re)install GRUB with the option `--force-extra-removable` to work around this part. I don't know anything Arch- specific about this.

Comment: Thank you, I will retry grub install with that flag. I updated my question to include fdisk -l output for my boot drive

Comment: The `--removable` flag when running `grub-install` seemed to do the trick! My version of `grub-install` did not have a `--force-extra-removable` flag, but `--removable` worked

Comment: My bad this was a Debian patch option. Anyway, this is supposed to be a work-around: you should still figure out what went wrong with UEFI boot